# Getting started with Magento REST API

Tags: magento-1.8, api, ce-1.8.1.0, rest-api, oauth

So the official documentation is very terse (bad!), particularly for someone who hasn't worked with REST/Oauth in the past.  I'm using Magento 1.8.1 CE.

Can somebody provide a simple PHP example of how to use Magento's REST API?

Using their example code (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html) I get two errors:

```
Message: Undefined index: state
Message: Use of undefined constant OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI - assumed 'OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI'
```

Thus far I've done:

- Install php oauth extension
- Create at least one product in Magento
- Configure resource permissions for Admin REST user for retrieving all product data for Admin
- Create a Consumer

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I narrowed down the problem to (surprise, surprise!) OAuth not working properly.  I gave up and changed the Guest roles and attributes to allow all.  Then, I tested things to see if they were working by navigating to:

```
http://yourdomain/api/rest/products
http://yourdomain/api/rest/products/1/images
```

Everything is indeed working.  If/when I figure out how to properly deal with authentication, I'll post the answer.

Comment: You can use the examples listed in here for authentication. http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-Authentication. (scroll down until you see code) There is one for guest/customer and one for admin login. They are basically the same, only the url called is different. They worked nicely for me.

Comment: I'll have a look.  I have guest working now, so I'm messing up authentication.  Thanks for the tip.  Also, did you have to create a oauth_admin.php file yourself? (sorry if this is explained in the linked article, but I figured I'd ask you since you have it working (:-).

Answer (score 2):

So [@user2636834](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3136/user2636834) did you figure this one out already?

I remember when I was setting up a test scenario that I got the sames error(s). Seemed that I didn't have Oauth installed :O. So in short I did (running Ubuntu and [following these instructions](http://webkul.com/blog/ubuntu-oauth-installation/), also running into [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772854/attempting-to-install-oauth-on-ubuntu-but-getting-errors)):

```
pecl install oauth
```

Then add `extension=oauth.so` to `php.ini`'s "Dynamic Extensions" section.
Then restart Apache

I tried the examples from the Magento site and got an error from the API:

> "Invalid auth/bad request"

I had to add a `'Accept' => '*/*'` header to the `$oauthClient->fetch()` call. After that it worked all just fine.

Hope you can get things running if you hadn't already.

Comment: I posted a similar problem here--> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63611/getting-403-forbidden-response-with-rest-api-on-ce-1-9-1-0. I tried adding `'Accept' => '*/*'` to `$oauthClient->fetch()` and still get a `403 Forbidden` response. Someone else said they solved the 403 after installing SSL. Is that really necessary? (just to be clear, I have Oauth installed and I'm only getting a 403 error - no other errors)