# How to install php_oauth.dll file

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, rest-api

i am unable to install php_oauth.dll file onto my system therefore not able to see it installed using phpinfo() what i have tried so far: i have downloaded the .dll files for both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems and updated my php.ini file to add the extension but still unable to show it inside phpinfo(),i want to work with magento REST api therefore i need it to be in working state.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its belongs to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Comment: sure go ahead..

Comment: @ArslanSohail, you might want to check this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/56075/3326

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with Magento REST API](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25447/getting-started-with-magento-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

u need to download the file php_oauth.dll (windows)

Copy that into

```
/bin/php[version]/ext
```

And you need to change php.ini to load oauth (Dynamic Extensions)

```
extension=php_oauth.dll
```